# how to add label over background image tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

button, label etc over an background image using tkinter. few days before I just stared learning python so I am sorry if this question look silly.. my code is below.. but at this moment label is showing below image not over image..please correct me.

```
import tkinter

haren = tkinter.Tk()

width, height = haren.winfo_screenwidth(), haren.winfo_screenheight()
bg = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="img/bg.png")

panel1 = tkinter.Label(haren, image=bg)
panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')

haren.wm_title("Hi Sana")
haren.grid()
yeah=tkinter.Label(haren, text="Developed by Full Mad Haren Sarma")
yeah.pack()
haren.wm_geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height))
haren.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, if you want both the image and the text to be visible, the window must be big enough for both. If the background image is exactly as large as your screen size, the text will be hidden. You can reveal the text by increasing the window size (I recommend testing with a smaller image), noting that it collapses under the image when you shrink the window.

Try changing your geometry manager to [`grid`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) instead of `pack`.

```
panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
```

changes to:

```
panel1.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

and

```
yeah.pack()
```

changes to:

```
yeah.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='s')
```

Note how both widgets are added to the same row and column, so the most recently-`grid()`ed widget will appear on top of previous ones. The `sticky` option indicates where in its `grid` square the widget will rest (the south end in this case).